# How to use google cloud storage in dataflow pipeline run from datalab

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-datalab

We've been running a Python pipeline in datalab that reads image files from a bucket in google cloud storage (importing google.datalab.storage). Originally we were using DirectRunner and this worked fine, but now we're trying to use DataflowRunner, and we're having import errors. Even if we include "import google.datalab.storage" or any variant thereof inside the function run by the pipeline, we get errors such as "No module named 'datalab.storage'". We've also tried using the save_main_session, requirements_file, and setup_file flags with no luck. How would we correctly access image files in cloud storage buckets in a dataflow pipeline?

EDIT: My original error was due to specifying the requirements_file flag with incorrect syntax (i.e. "--requirements_file ./requirements.txt"). I think I've fixed the syntax there, but now I'm getting a different error. Here's a basic version of the code we're trying to run- we have a pipeline that reads files from a storage bucket in Google Cloud.
We have a datalab notebook with a cell containing the following Python code:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.utils.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.utils.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.utils.pipeline_options import StandardOptions
import google.datalab.storage as storage

bucket = "BUCKET_NAME"
shared_bucket = storage.Bucket(bucket)

# Create and set PipelineOptions. 
options = PipelineOptions(flags = ["--requirements_file", "./requirements.txt"])
google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
google_cloud_options.project = "PROJECT_NAME"
google_cloud_options.job_name = 'test-pipeline-requirements'
google_cloud_options.staging_location = 'gs://BUCKET_NAME/binaries'
google_cloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://BUCKET_NAME/temp'
options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'

def read_file(input_tuple):
  filepath = input_tuple[0]
  shared_object = shared_bucket.object(filepath)
  f = shared_object.read_stream()
  # More processing of f's contents
  return input_tuple

# File paths relative to the bucket
input_tuples = [("FILEPATH_1", "UNUSED_FILEPATH_2")]
p = beam.Pipeline(options = options)
all_files = (p | "Create file path tuple" >> beam.Create(input_tuples))
all_files = (all_files | "Read file" >> beam.FlatMap(read_file))
p.run()
```

Meanwhile there is a file named "requirements.txt" in the same directory as the notebook, with only the line

```
datalab==1.0.1
```

This code works fine if I use DirectRunner. However, when I use DataflowRunner, I get a CalledProcessError at "p.run()", with stack trace ending with the following:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/dependency.pyc in _populate_requirements_cache(requirements_file, cache_dir)
>       224       '--no-binary', ':all:']
>       225   logging.info('Executing command: %s', cmd_args)
>   --> 226   processes.check_call(cmd_args)
>       227
>       228
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/utils/processes.pyc in check_call(*args, **kwargs)
>        38   if force_shell:
>        39     kwargs['shell'] = True
>   ---> 40   return subprocess.check_call(*args, **kwargs)
>        41
>        42
>
> /usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
>       538         if cmd is None:
>       539             cmd = popenargs[0]
>   --> 540         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
>       541     return 0
>       542
>
> CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--download', '/tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache', '-r', './requirements.txt', '--no-binary', ':all:']' returned non-zero exit status 1

It seems like the "--download" option is deprecated for pip, but that's part of the apache_beam code. I've also tried this with different ways of specifying "requirements.txt", with and without the "--save_main_session" flag, and with and without the "--setup_file" flag, but no dice.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as the exact error message you are getting when trying to run this code?

Answer (score 4):

If your only usage of pydatalab is to read from GCS, then I would suggest using Dataflow's gcsio. Code example:

```
def read_file(input_tuple):
  filepath = input_tuple[0]
  with beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    # process f content
    pass

# File paths relative to the bucket
input_tuples = [("gs://bucket/file.jpg", "UNUSED_FILEPATH_2")]
p = beam.Pipeline(options = options)
all_files = (p | "Create file path tuple" >> beam.Create(input_tuples))
all_files = (all_files | "Read file" >> beam.FlatMap(read_file))
p.run()
```

pydatalab is pretty heavy since it is more of an data exploration library used with Datalab or Jupyter. On the other hand, Dataflow's GCSIO is natively supported in pipeline.

Comment: This would be better, but does this require the "--save_main_session" flag? That's currently giving me strange pickling errors...

Comment: @BradleyJiang can you just clarify your answer. By executing read_file, you are bringing the objects from gcp bucket to local system? They are stored in cwd()?, so further down in the pipeline, we could read them by supplying "filepath" or is that the location on the bucket, not the local system? I'm confused whether this is passing the byte stream, or actually saving to a local path. I want to save.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely issue is that you need to have Dataflow install the [datalab pypi module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/datalab).

Typically you would do this by listing "datalab" in the requirements.txt file you upload to Dataflow.  See https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dependencies-python

Comment: We have attempted this, but it doesn't seem to be working (see edit above). Is there something else we're missing, or some issue with the DataflowRunner itself? (using a deprecated pip flag)

Comment: Divya, Which version of Apache_beam are you using?

Comment: Looks like it was version 0.6.0.
I upgraded to version 2.0.0 and got a different error in apache_beam/transforms/trigger.py: (ImportError: cannot import name TimestampCombiner), related to the second step in my pipeline. 
When I comment out
    `#  all_files = (all_files | "Read file" >> beam.FlatMap(read_file))`
I again get the original CalledProcessError.